# Scalaz === on Some

Tags: scala, scalaz

Difficulty in understanding the behaviour of === in scalaz

```
1. scala> 1.some === Some(1)
   res33: Boolean = true

2. scala> Some(1) === 1.some
   <console>:14: error: value === is not a member of Some[Int]
              Some(1) === 1.some
                      ^

3. scala> (Some(1):Option[Int]) === 1.some
   res35: Boolean = true
```

I can understand (1) and I expect even (2) to give same result.

In (3) I had to cast Some to Option to get the result.

I looked at the source code of scalaz but couldn't get it.

Please explain.

Scalaz Version = 7.1.0

Scala Version = 2.11.2

Comment: Seems related to the Scala version. Works as expected with Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan oh yes it works well with Scala 2.10.4

Can this be a bug in Scalaz then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Some(1)` returns `Some[Int]` rather than `Option[Int]`; the whole point of `.some` is to return `Option[Int]` instead to be more compatible with the scalaz style. Scalaz is written for a non-subtyping ADT-based programming style and most scalaz typeclasses have very little support for subtyping (in particular, they're usually invariant; often this improves type inference and means better error messages when users make mistakes, but at the cost of poorer support for subtypes). If you're making heavy use of scalaz, you will probably find it easiest to use scalaz-style "smart constructors" like `.some` all the time.

Comment: I see few typeclasses which are invarient. This takes away some flexibility. 
But otherwise as @IonuțG.Stan pointed it works with scala 2.10.4. Can this be issue with cross compiling done by scalaz?

Comment: I don't know; my point is more that Scalaz doesn't support this use style, and may well not consider this a bug.